# Custom Validation when TextBox has value and CheckBox does not

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I have a situauation that I need to check on a button click if the user has entered a value into a textbox, but have not checked a checkbox.  They need to be advised that they can not enter a value in the textbox without first checking the checkbox.  I know I need to use a CustomValidator Control, but other than that I'm lost.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: why not have the textbox disabled and when the user checks the checkbox enable the textbox?

Comment: @SaverioTerracciano It's a conversion of a classic site.  All of the functionality has to match that of the old site.  I hoped to use a custom validation control, because I'm using a validation summary which looks exaclty like what they are doing in the old site.

Answer (score 1):

In OnClientClick event you can call a javascript method which will do this validation for you.

This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't really know JavaScript all that well.  I was hoping someone would be able to help me with code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do so will be enabling/disabling the textbox base on whether the checkbox is checked.

However, if you want to do the check on button_click, maybe just do checks on both the `checkbox` and `textbox`? And output error message to a label or something?

```
if(TextBox1.Text.Trim() != "")
    if(!CheckBox1.Checked)
        label1.Text = "Checkbox needs to be checked";
```

Or, you can do checks when `TextBox1.Text` has changed.

```
private void Textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!CheckBox1.Checked)
        label1.Text = "Checkbox needs to be checked";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the "easiest way to do so will be enabling/disabling the textbox based on the checkbox value. Preventing the user from making the mistake in the first place is a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this functality using javascript/Jquery.Set the onClientClick property of button as below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onClientClick="ValidateData();"/>
```

Below is the jquery code:

```
function ValidateData()
{
if(!$('#checkboxID').is(':checked') && $.trim($('#textBoxID').val())!='')
{
alert('Please check the checkbox before entering text');
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

First you must have a button like this...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheck" runat="server" CssClass="m-btn purple" Text="Check" onclintclick="Validate()"/>
```

Now we can write the validation script...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function Validate() {

            if(document.getelementid('checkbox1').checked==true)
            {
              if(document.getelementid('Textbox1').value=="")
              {
               //Write your code here..
              }  
            }
            else
            {
               alert('Please check the checkbox..');
            }
        }
  </script>
```

Please feel free to mark as answer if it satisfies you....